# How to make directory modification date change when files from that dir change?

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, directory, io

For example, if a file has been changed in that directory, then directory modification date should be updated. Basically any changes that happen in that directory should trigger a "touch" on the directory.

Can I make the system do that automatically when these file operations are performed?

If yes, could also the parent directories be 'touched', until root?

Comment: Moving a file into a directory should update that directory's modification date, that's the default behavior. What file system do you use? And which operating system?

Comment: it's linux 2.6.32 and file system shows "ext3"

Comment: And you're _sure_ that moving a file into a directory does not change the directory's mod date? Very strange.

Comment: you're right, it does on file move. Also works on rename and delete (sorry didn't know). But it doesn't on file content change :(

Comment: OK, could you please [edit] your question so it asks what you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) interface to perform an action when a file is modified. From the shell, you can use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

```
inotifywait -e modify --format '%f' /path/to/directory |
while read line; do
  if [ -n "$line" ]; then touch /path/to/directory; fi
done
```

If you want to update the timestamp of `/path/to/directory` when a file is modified in a subdirectory as well, add the `-r` option to `inotifywait`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84346/26112).

To touch the directory and all of its parent directories, run something along the lines of this (untested):

```
dir=/path/to/directory
inotifywait -e modify --format '%f' "$dir" |
while read line; do
   if [ -n "$line" ]; then
      # Handle relative paths.
      if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -c1)" != / ] ; then
          path=.
      fi

      echo "$dir" | tr '/' '\n' |
      while read part ; do
         touch "$path/$part"
      done
   fi
done
```